# Return the contents of a div if it contains a word to console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

onClicked browser action I would like to look for a div containing the word fitness and print it's contents to console.log however I'm struggling to get the below code working but I can't see what's wrong.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    console.log('this prints to console');

    //This function does not return anything
    $( "div:contains('ingredients')" ).length > 0) {
      console.log(text);
    };

    console.log('this also prints to console');
});
```

The `console.log(text)` fails to return anything or any errors. Im assuming this function is not constructed properly. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the div I am after:

```
<div class="cN-simpleList listIngredients" itemprop="ingredients">
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find a question. Are there any errors? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: `text` is undefined ... use `var text = $( "div:contains('ingredients')" ).text()`

Comment: see my answer to another question how you [execute scripts on a page as a reaction to the browserAction trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34592581/2445882)

Answer (score 0):

I just wonder if you have put these code in background page and want to get content dom?

You can't get DOM in background page and you might need to pass the DOM from content script to either a background page or popup for futher work.
Refer [Official Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) for more details, especially Content Scripts and Event Pages.