# Simulate clicking elements on the page from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to iterate and click all the elements with the class `.star_gray` on page, and keep the iteration and clicking going after redirection. Running JavaScript code cannot meet the second requirement, so I plan to write a Chrome Extension.

But I failed to simulate clicking events on web pages via the extension. My project is as below:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Check'em All",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["file:///*"],
    "js"     : ["popup.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Check'em All!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Check'em All!</h1>
  <button id="check-btn">BUTTON</button>
  <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('check-btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', injectScript);
});

function injectScript() {
  alert('Handler called!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'background.js' });
}
```

**background.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.star_gray').click();
  $('a.btn.page_next').click();
});
```

With the code above, when I click the button(`#check-btn`) on the popup, nothing happens.

Comment: `document.getElementById('#check-btn');` is wrong. Remove the `#` symbol. You _could_ use that with `document.querySelector`, since it will signify that the following text is an id. However, with a function that's only looking in elements IDs, it's superfluous and a mistake.

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry that was a typo. The code still doesn't work without the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get access DOM in background page. And per your code, you might need to learn more from [Official Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), since it seems you are confused with "popup", "background" and "content".

Assuming you want to trigger the click event for all elements with class    ".star_gray" in the content page, the following code trigger those events once you click on browserAction.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "description": "Test",
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "title": "Test"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {command: "click"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.result);
        });
    });
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)    {
    $('.star_gray').click();
    $('a.btn.page_next').click();

    sendResponse({result: "success"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Now the message is sent successfully between content and background, yet the code other than the `sendResponse` in content_script doesn't work.

Comment: why are you suggesting `tabs` permission for something that can be done with [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! Since I was querying tabs, I will need the tabs permission. However, you can also just declare activeTab permission and use "chrome.browser.Action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){...});" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Improving the previous answer by @haibara-ai not to use the [`tabs` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Note that in your case you don't even need to watch for `ready()` since the script runs only when browser action is triggered which is presumably well after `DOMContentLoaded`.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "description": "Test",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "title": "Test"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
var files = [
    'jquery.js',
    'content.js',
];

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    for (var file of files) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: file,
            allFrames: true,
        });
    }
});
```

content.js

```
$('.star_gray').click();
$('a.btn.page_next').click();
```

Note, however that this only solves the 'simulate clicking events on web pages via the extension' question. It does not mean that 'keep the iteration and clicking going after redirection' will work. It's best you create another question with the details of what exactly you mean by that.