# Chrome Extension - click on element (button) on the page using hotkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm trying to click a particular button on the page using a hotkey that will trigger a javascript that will do that.
But no matter what I tried, I'm getting "`click of undefined`"

Hotkey thing is working perfectly, but the only issue is clicking on that element (button) which has no ID, only `class`

here is my manifest.json

```
    {
    "name": "Clicking plugin",
    "description": "Just a simple pluugin",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["script.js"]
    },
    "commands": {
    "endorse_cmd": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+X"
      },
      "description": "nothing"
    },
    "claim_cmd": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Y"
        },
        "description": "nothing"
        }
    }
}
```

here is my script.js

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white');
var votedUp = document.getElementsByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white VotingButton--votedUp');
var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('task-skip-submit js-next-question');
var elems2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-next-task js-next-question');



chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command == "endorse_cmd") {
        alert("X Pressed"); //this works
        if (votedUp.length > 0){ elems1[0].click(); } else if (elems.length > 0){ elems[0].click(); elems1[0].click(); } else if (elems2.length > 0){ elems2[0].click();} else if (elems1.length > 0){ elems1[0].click();} //This is not working
        
        }
        else if (command == "claim_cmd") {
            alert("Y Pressed"); //this works
            var claimBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-blue js-claim-question claim-button');//This is not working
            claimBtn[0].click();//This is not working
        }
});
```

a button that I want to click looks like this:

```
<button class="btn-blue js-claim-question claim-button">Claim questions</button>
```

Comment: Ctrl+x and Ctrl+y are already keystrokes. You have to create your own keystroke that isn't already defined by chrome. Ctrl+X is used to cut and Ctrl+Y is used to redo (mainly in text inputs)

Comment: In my case, it's working, it gives me the Alert, so it means it's successfully pressed.
also, I am getting "click of undefined", which means that he tried to click, but can't find the element

Comment: I'm pretty sure in `getElementsByClassName` you can only specify one class. You could use `classList` after getting one element that matches and do that for each class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to programming, I write codes based mostly on google-ing and editing them a little. so If you don't mind write the solution? @Rojo

Comment: Nevermind, I looked at the documentation and what you did is fine

Comment: but still doesn't work... :/

Comment: Have you declared [permissions in your manifest?](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/declare_permissions/)

Comment: I did, still nothing...

Comment: What is the output of console.log(claimBtn)?

Comment: maybe I've missed some permissions... Can you tell me which permissions I have to grant? So far I've granted "background", "active Tab",  "tabs"

Let me check what is the output, I'll let you know in a few minutes

Comment: @Rojo nothing, I tried to console.log it, but it literally doesn't show anything in the console, although I see "messages" count on the console left sidebar, but I can't access it

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588961/10210841)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't access the activeTab DOM from a background script. You need to run [`executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) with the code that will get the info and simulate the click:

Background script:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: `
    var claimBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-blue js-claim-question claim-button');
    claimBtn[0].click();`
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  /* other things */
  permissions: [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Put the code I have provided for the background script in the <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> command.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined
Context: _generated_background_page.html

Comment: @DeanMisic Sorry. I realized you don't need the onclick. try it now

Comment: IT WORKS OMG, THANK YOU!! 
Can you make it for ctrl+x as well? Thank you very much !!!

Comment: I did it for ctrl+x, I can't thank you enough @Rojo !! Accepted your solution